# Homological algebra generalization of covering map

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homological-algebra, covering-spaces

I would like to know if there exists an operation in homological algebra that generalizes the notion of covering maps for abstract chain complexes (over any field or ring, or maybe just certains where it works, for any length, or maybe up to a certain length), in the spirit of chain maps, homotopic maps, mapping cones... that generalize topological operations.

Otherwise, what would be an operation between chain complexes, that resemble the most a covering operation, except the trivial $X=\tilde{X}\otimes_{K[G]} K$ of taking co-invariants, for some chain complex $\tilde{X}$ with a linear $G$ action because here $X$ is constructed given $\tilde{X}$, and in the spirit I would like an operation that "construct" $\tilde{X}$ from $X$, like one would be able to do in topology for regular CW complex $X$. Maybe this would be a process that creates a triangulated complex out of $X$ and compute its fundamental group...

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean anything different from (co)fibres of chain maps? Because for a chain map $f:X\to Y$ between complexes you obtain a bicomplex and then take its total complex, things like that. Moreover you have easy to work with models for all kinds of homotopy (co)limits of complexes, etc.

Comment: Perhaps you're looking for Shapiro's lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapiro%27s_lemma)? One version says that the homology of a covering space is isomorphic to ordinary homology with coefficients in the induced representation.

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე indeed I know that the mapping cone of a map can be seen as the total complex of a double complex built from the complexes but I am not familiar with fibre of chain map, or on how it can be related to my question.

Comment: @HJRW, isn't homology with local coefficient still relying on topology since the group ring in the tensor has to be a Z[\pi_1] module. I think my question can be restated as follows: what is a choice of a local coefficient system for general chains that mimic local coefficient systems in topology.

Comment: It could have a diagrammatic approach like proposed in the first comment or an algebraic one, related to coefficient system in topology and probably less general that Shapiro's lemma as pointed in the second comment

Comment: There’s no fundamental group of an abstract chain complex over a ring, so there won’t be any generalization of covering.

Comment: For chain complexes fibers are constructed using the straightforward dual of the cone construction, $d:X_n\oplus Y_{n+1}\to X_{n-1}\oplus Y_n$ is given by $d(x,y)=(dx,fx\pm dy)$. Thus a cycle of the fibre is a cycle of $X$ equipped with the witness of the fact that its $f$-image is a boundary.